# VB.Net and MySQL

Tags: mysql, vb.net, foreign-keys, primary-key

I am using VB.Net and MySQL as it's database, I'm a newbie. I have a problem using Foreign key in MySQL. In MySQL, I've created `inq` Table as its primary table and `inqcontact` Table. Here's my MySQL code:

```
CREATE TABLE inq(
     number INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     lastname VARCHAR(20),
     firstname VARCHAR(20),
     middlename VARCHAR(20),
     PRIMARY KEY(number));

CREATE TABLE inqcontact(
     noinqcontact INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     mobile VARCHAR(20),
     telephone VARCHAR(20),
     emailadd VARCHAR(20),
     number INT,
     PRIMARY KEY(noinqcontact),
     FOREIGN KEY(number) REFERENCES inq(number));
```

and here's my VB.Net code:

```
CommInq1 = New MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO inq VALUES (number,'" & txtLastName.Text & "','" & txtFirstName.Text & "','" & txtMiddleName.Text & "')", ConnInq)
        ConnInq.Open()
        CommInq1.ExecuteNonQuery()

        CommInq2 = New MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO inqcontact VALUES (noinqcontact,'" & txtMobileNo.Text & "','" & txtTelephoneNo.Text & "','" & txtEmailAdd.Text & "',number )", ConnInq)
        CommInq2.ExecuteNonQuery()
        ConnInq.Close()

        MessageBox.Show("Saved!", "")
```

My VB.Net code returns NULL value to the `number` Foreign Key in `inqcontact` Table. I mean, in `inq` Table, the `number` field automatically increments itself so there's no problem with it. But in `inqcontact` Table, the `number` Field, which is the Foreign Key, is NULL value. Could you tell me what's wrong with the code I've provided? I think, the error is in the insertion of data from my VB.Net.

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
CommInq1 = New MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO inq (lastname,firstname,middlename)
                 VALUES (@lastname,@firstname,@middlename)",ConnInq)

CommInq1.Parameters.Add("@lastname",MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDbType.VarChar,20).Value=txtLastName.Text
CommInq1.Parameters.Add("@firstname",MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDbType.VarChar,20).Value=txtFirstName.Text
CommInq1.Parameters.Add("@middlename",MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDbType.VarChar,20).Value=txtMiddleName.Text

ConnInq.Open()
CommInq1.ExecuteNonQuery()

CommInq2 = New MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO inqcontact (mobile,telephone,emailadd,number)  
                 VALUES (@mobile,@telephone,@emailadd,@number)",ConnInq)

CommInq2.Parameters.Add("@mobile",MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDbType.VarChar,20).Value=txtMobileNo.Text
CommInq2.Parameters.Add("@telephone",MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDbType.VarChar,20).Value=txtTelephoneNo.Text
CommInq2.Parameters.Add("@emailadde",MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDbType.VarChar,20).Value=txtEmailAdd.Text
CommInq2.Parameters.Add("@number",MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDbType.Int32)
       .Value=CommInq1.LastInsertedId  
             ' or use select last_insert_id() to get the last id

CommInq2.ExecuteNonQuery()
ConnInq.Close()
```

Comment: All fields are **NULL** with your code. I tried to insert using _MySQL Command Line Client_ with the code I used prior to yours:

`INSERT INTO inq VALUES(number,'SomeText','SomeText','SomeText');`
and that fills the four fields. But this one:

`INSERT INTO inqcontact VALUES(noinqcontact,'SomeText','Sometext',SomeText',number);`

the first to fourth fields are ok but the last(**number**), which is the foreign key, was not...

So, there's no wrong with my VB.Net Syntax. I think it's in my MySQL syntax.

Answer (score 2):

I generally use SQL server rather than my SQL, but I believe that you should be able to do basically the following:

```
CommInq1 = New MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO inq (lastname,firstname,middlename)
                 VALUES (@lastname,@firstname,@middlename); select last_insert_id()" ,ConnInq)
CommInq1.Parameters.Add("@lastname",MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDbType.VarChar,20).Value=txtLastName.Text
CommInq1.Parameters.Add("@firstname",MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDbType.VarChar,20).Value=txtFirstName.Text
CommInq1.Parameters.Add("@middlename",MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDbType.VarChar,20).Value=txtMiddleName.Text

ConnInq.Open()
Dim id as Integer = cint(CommInq1.ExecuteScalar())
```

And then proceed with the second query using id as the value for the inserted item's key.  I copied the code from the answer above because its more proper (security against injection and all) and a habit, but the ; followed by the second query to get the id just inserted should work with your query as well.